# How to keep changes after saving in Jekyll using VS Code

Tags: jekyll

I am new to Jekyll and setting up my first blog site. I opened the newly generated Jekyll folder in VS Code and made changes to the index.html file, saved it, and then viewed it on localhost:4000. I made changes to I see the small changes at first, but then a few minutes later the changes I made are gone, and the site looks as it did when I first generated it. I am not sure why this is happening. I have tried searching google and stack overflow for an answer but have not found anything that can tell me why my saved changes are not staying and how I can get them to stay.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the `_site` folder are *regenerated* automatically every time you make changes elsewhere.
**Never make changes to contents in `_site` manually — it's pointless**

To customize your site, instead make changes to files outside the `_site` directory.
Read the entire page at the following link to get a good grasp at customizing your theme's templates: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/